# Implementing on a FPGA Nexys3 board

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I made a project in VHDL that works well on the Active-HDL simulator. The code works like this: The user inserts a certain number of numbers (2,4,8 or 16),generated pseudo-random, and then the result is the average of the numbers.
The problem is that, even though it works on Active-HDL, I implemented it on a Nexys 3 Xilinx, using ISE design suite and the numbers do not correspond to what I wanted. Any ideas why this can occur generally?

Comment: If you want help on a problem like this it's very helpful if you post some of your code.  You don't have to post everything, just the code that's relevant to the question you're asking.

Comment: yes, definitely include more details about your code and what you want it to do.